# efficient way to read csv with numeric data in python

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, numpy

I try to convert a code writen in Matlab into python.
I'm trying to read dat file (it's a csv file). that file has about 30 columns and thousands of rows containing (only!) decimal number data (in Matlab it was read into double matrix).
I'm asking for the fastest way to read the dat file and the most similar object/array/... to save the data into.

I tried to read the file in both of the following ways:

```
my_data1 = numpy.genfromtxt('FileName.dat', delimiter=',' )
my_data2 = pd.read_csv('FileName.dat',delimiter=',')
```

Is there any better option?

Comment: Better...how? What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: What do you want to do with these data?

Comment: 30 columns, 1000s of rows doesn't sound all that big.  If the file is really big you should be worrying more about the memory needed to store and process the data.   What's the size of the matrix in MATLAB?

Comment: `my_data1` is probably a 2d array, and close in character to the MATLAB matrix.  `my_data2` is a dataframe, and may contain `my_data1` or multiple arrays that amount to the same thing.

Comment: I would like to do some data processing such as filtering, interpolations, spectogram and pwelch (the data is EEG data - floating point with 15 decimal digits). As I said, the file has about 30 columns and 100,000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

`pd.read_csv` is pretty efficient as it is. To make it faster, you can use try to use multiple cores to load your data in parallel. Here is some code example where I used `joblib` when I needed to make data loading with `pd.read_csv` and processing of that data faster.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import dirname, abspath, isfile, join
import pandas as pd
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
# Multi-threading
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing
# Garbage collector
import gc

# Number of cores
TOTAL_NUM_CORES = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
# Path of this script's file
DATA_PATH = 'D:\\'
# Path to save the processed files
TARGET_PATH = 'C:\\'

def read_and_convert(f,num_files):
    #global i
    # Read the file
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH + f, low_memory=False, header=None, names=['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Bid', 'Ask'], index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
    # Process the data
    data_ask_bid = process_data(dataframe)
    # Store processed data in target folder
    data_ask_bid.to_csv(TARGET_PATH + f)
    print(f)
    # Garbage collector. I needed to use this, otherwise my memory would get full after a few files, but you might not need it.
    gc.collect()

def main():
    # Counter for converted files
    global i
    i = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    # Get the paths for all the data files
    files_names = [f for f in listdir(DATA_PATH) if isfile(join(DATA_PATH, f))]

    # Load and process files in parallel
    Parallel(n_jobs=TOTAL_NUM_CORES)(delayed(read_and_convert)(f,len(files_names)) for f in files_names)
    # for f in files_names: read_and_convert(f,len(files_names)) # non-parallel
    print("\nTook %s seconds." % (time.time() - start_time))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How do I run this code?
Is the DATA_PATH is the name of the raw csv file?
what is the TARGET_PATH used for?